# Adding a new switch with an independent light in an existing circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have two switches at the bottom of my stairs in the basement. One switch is a three way to the switch at the top of my stairs. The other switch lights a series of lights all connected to the same circuit.
One of those lights is in the pantry and what I would like to do is isolate that light from the rest by adding a single pole switch to the room.
The switch at the bottom of the stairs would still light up the rest of the lights.

[image: Bottom of stairs one single pole switch to a group of lights a three way switch to the top of the stairs]
[image: Hot lead from dual switch bottom of stairs going into the pantry room]
[image: First light in the series that are activated by the switch at the bottom of stairs.]
[image: Second light in the series that I want to isolate from the rest. This light is in the pantry that requires its own switch]

[image: Inside the box at the bottom of the stairs]

Comment: It depends on how it is wired if that light has a run to the switch location you could be in luck and adding a 2 switch on 1 yoke could bee all that is needed but some photos of the wires in the switch box would be helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: How hard would it be to feed a new cable from the bottom-of-the-basement-stairs switch box to the pantry?

Comment: I can add a new hot from the bottom of the stairs or I can make a junction in the ceiling and feed the new switch and existing light. Not sure if that works or not?

Comment: I could show photos but not sure how to do that as I am a bit of a newb in this forum

Comment: Is there an always-hot available in the ceiling?  Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for the bottom-of-stairs switches for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input by the contributors, I was able to make an informed decision. I passed a new cable down through the wall to the main switch box at the bottom of the stairs. I wired in the new wire and passed the wire across to the pantry room. I removed the wire from the fixture and tied those together in a junction box. I passed the new cable down to the new box and passed a new wire from the box to the existing electrical box. The fixture box is plastic and doesn't have a ground screw so I just capped it off with a wire nut. I wired the light and the switch without any issue.